# VTK File: How do I save data on a cell face?

Tags: visualization, open-source, paraview, vtk

I am writing a program that creates a vtk file with a Rectilinear Grid. I am able to save data to each one of the cells using CELL_DATA, but now, I need to save data to each one of the cell faces (x6). How do I do that? Will I will be able visualize it in ParaView?

EDIT: In the VTK file format, if one create a 3d rectilinear grid dataset, the default cell will be 3 dimensional (8 points). Is there a way to create 2D cells with a 3D rectilinear grid?

Comment: "save data to each one of the cell faces" by itself does not mean very much. It could mean "I want to visualize data where each face has a value and cells will be shown as empty", or it could mean "I assign data to faces and expect that a particular interpolation happens from faces to the interior of the cells, for example using the Nedelec shape functions". You need to state in your question what exactly it is you want.

Comment: I mean mean exactly this: "I want to visualize data where each face has a value and cells will be shown as empty".

Answer (score 1):

The way this is done in the deal.II library (http://www.dealii.org; disclaimer: this is a project I am affiliated with) is that we describe an unstructured data set of 3d points and then create cells that happen to be two-dimensional. In other words, just output a set of quadrilaterals that happen to live in a three-dimensional space.

To give an example, here is a file that outputs a set of lines in a 2d space: https://github.com/bangerth/dealii/blob/master/tests/codim_one/data_out_02.output . You'd need to do something similar for 2d quads in a 3d space.